# Compare two parameters

Tags: sed, awk, grep, tr

I have two parameters:

```
security.server.port=8443
security.authorization.enabled=true
```

I want every time to check those parameters in file 
if one of them missing to add after the next one or opositive 
or if they missing at all to added after "security.server.ip="

For example:

If we have in the file parameter:

```
security.authorization.enabled=true
```

Expected View:

```
security.server.port=8443
security.authorization.enabled=true
```

Not able to create whole process grep and add after the grep

Comment: what if in you file there is `security.server.port=8888`? or `security.authorization.enabled=false`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   params["security.server.port=8443"]
   params["security.authorization.enabled=true"]
}

{
   for (param in params)
      if ($0 == param)
         params[param] = 1
   print
}

END {
   for (param in params)
      if (params[param] != 1)
         print param
}
' file
```

It's hard to say without more representative input and expected output.